# print all open tabs in adobe acrobat

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Ive got adobe acrobat (pro) as part of Adobe creative cloud subscription license.

When i open multiple PDFs at once acrobat opens each individual PDF as a tab.

If i want to print all of them i have to click into each tab and manually click print, is there a way i can get it to automatically print all open tabs ?

Im running this on my laptop - macbook pro, OSX 10.10.15.

Comment: I found this info about printing multiple PDF [link 1](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-do-I-print-multiple-PDF-files-in-a-a-batch-q25292.aspx) [link 2](http://khkonsulting.com/2015/04/create-custom-tools-in-adobe-acrobat-dc-pro/)

Comment: Thanks @spike_66 , its an options but seems quite a long work around for a basic feature to have to create a script